# Trying to use JSON with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to get json working using jQuery 1.4.1 but I'm getting a null object.

Here's an example of not working code: (using $.ajax which has the 'success:' )

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://isohunt.com/js/json.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert('Worked');
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

What is wrong with this code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you give us what is json.php or might as well just use $.getJSON() function

Comment: What exactly is not working? Is the alert box not shown? Do you get JSON data as response?

Comment: @Reigel: ajax is just a low-level function of getJSON, but getJSON lacks a success and error functionality. 
@Felix: the returned data object is null

Answer (score 3):

You cannot ajax cross domain. You have to make proxy instead, inside your domain. Check http://www.google.com/search?q=ajax+cross+domain

Comment: ...unless you point to a jsonp enabled domain, with a cross-site callback.

Comment: I see, I'll check that link. Currently I'm only testing this in a local server, would that be a problem ?

Comment: yes the browser won't let you make a plain XMLHttprequest to the other domain (isohunt.com)

Comment: The problem is that the server you're trying to contact is not your own... Regardless of remote or local.

Comment: If i were to add '?callback=?' to the url, I'm getting an error in the Firefox Console, but the first line is in fact visible... do you have any idea why it would be able to retrieve those first characters ?