# Can I load data from an external page via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've just starting learning jQuery and AJAX. I'm able to load a local page (on my disk) into a div via `jQuery.load()`, but external sites don't seem to work. I've even used wireshark to check if the data is being sent from the server (it is). Sample code is below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src='jquery-1.4.2.min.js'></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // $('#test').load('localpage.htm'); works!
            $('#test').load('http://www.google.com/'); // does not work!
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='test'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to do this in the first place? If so, how?

Comment: Similar question with answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217695/trying-to-use-json-with-jquery/2217707#2217707

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box: no. It's a security issue. There are a [few](http://www.ajax-cross-domain.com/) [different](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/cross_domain_aj) [workarounds](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/calling-cross-domain-web-services-in-ajax/) though.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do ajax calls to a different domain than the script originates from.

For doing such a thing, you have to use a proxy page on your own page, eg:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#test').load('ajax/getgoogle.php');
    });
</script>
```

getgoogle.php:

```
<?php

echo file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/");

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're running into the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).  You can't access data from an external domain using AJAX, it's considered a security risk.  The reasoning behind it is that AJAX requests work with cookies stored by the browser -- if I tried to access facebook.com, and you were logged in there, the cookie would be sent and I'd have access to your personal data.

Answer (score 2):

For security reasons, you cannot use AJAX to request a page from a different domain (or protocol or port).

Instead, you can write a server-side script on your server to forward requests to another domain.  (This is not possible if you're running a page from a `file://` url)

Comment: I'm not sure if you meant HTTP redirection or proxying by `to forward requests to another domain` - the former wouldn't work but forwarding wouldn't be the correct term for the latter.

Comment: sorry, I'm just being picky when there's really no need (stress of the job, maybe? ;-)).  I suppose forwarding could be used as a term, but it just read wrong to me and I almost downvoted ;-)

Comment: Do you know of a more precise verb?

Comment: Proxy is the correct term. Not that it really matters; your point is clear. :)

Answer (score 2):

Ajax? Yes. XHR? [No](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) (unless the browser implements [Cross-site XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control) which isn't widespread yet).

To get the data with Ajax without using XHR the external site must provide the data in the [JSONP format](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/).

Alternatively, you can proxy the data through a server side script on your server, thus making it come from the same host (as far as JavaScript is concerned).

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not. Have a look at [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). The site you are trying to request would need to have [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) enabled for that to work, and you would utilize a [cross-domain callback](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/107136.aspx). Alternatively, you could create a proxy on your own domain which grabs the page on behalf of your ajax request.

Answer (score 2):

Load this PHP script instead of trying to load website directly

```
$filename = "http://www.sitename.com";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
if ($handle)
{
    while (!feof($handle))
    {
        $text .= fread($handle, 128);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
print $text;
```

Edit: Or simply like henchman's solution with *file_get_contents*

Comment: Use cURL in preference to fopen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636678/what-are-the-important-differences-between-using-fopenurl-and-curl-in-php/637693

Answer (score 0):

You can't call Ajax from another domain. Check JSON technique for this

Comment: JSON won't help you here as it is just a format for doing e.g. ajax calls. Same origin policy strikes here, too.

Comment: He might be referring to JSONP.