# javascript load content into div error:0

Tags: javascript, load, xmlhttprequest, activexobject

I am using javascript to pull data from a URL and put it into a div:

```
function ahah(url, target) {
    document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = 'Fetching fixtures...';
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
if (req != undefined) {
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {ahahDone(url, target);};
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.send("");
    }
}  

function ahahDone(url, target) {
    if (req.readyState == 4) { // only if req is "loaded"
        if (req.status == 200) { // only if "OK"
            document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = req.responseText;
        } else {
            document.getElementById(target).innerHTML=" Error:\n"+ req.status + "\n" +req.statusText;
        }
    }
}

function load(name, div) {
    ahah(name,div);
return false;
}

load('http://www.domain.com/feeds/','content');
```

The problem is that if the URL to load is local it works fine (/feeds/), but when I change it to point to an external site (http://www.domain.com/feeds/) where I intend to hold the file I get an 'Error 0'.

I have checked the URL has the content available but unless it is local it will not work. Any feedback is very welcome, thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I load data from an external page via AJAX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409581/can-i-load-data-from-an-external-page-via-ajax)

Comment: It is impossible to load data from another domain unless specific cases.

Answer (score 1):

An 'error' of 0 simply means that the request loaded on the local machine. Nothing to worry about :)

Just change this line of code to accept a status of 0:

`if (req.status == 200 || req.status == 0) {`

Edit: As some commenters have mentioned, you could have domain-origin problems as well, though I don't believe that is the problem in this instance.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added this line and it got rid of the error, but no content has loaded into the div. (It still works if I have it local).

Comment: No errors in the console even? Try sticking the whole function in a `try` `catch` block and see if anything happens. Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: Hi Jeffrey. No errors in the console and I tried the 'try and catch', no errors returned. It just doesn't like using a remote server :(

Comment: And that domain definitely exists? I don't know what else to advise, sorry :|

Comment: Yes the URL with the content defiantly exists. I have opened the javascript file via the page I am trying to load it on, copied and pasted the url into the address bar and its all there.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the html pages you are trying to fetch should reside on your website (domain). The html fragments you try to fetch from other sites wont be fetched.